# Not able to display data inside dropdown after typing "@"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a scenario in which there is an input field, where I want that when a user types "@", a dropdown should appear automatically that will have a list of dynamic data and then the user can select a value from dropdown as it is done in the normal dropdown.

I am able to capture the value "@" so that I know when the user has typed it, and also I am able to fetch the list of dynamic data through ajax, but I am not able to display the data inside a dropdown as soon as the user has typed @

It should look something like this
[image]

Can anyone please help me with it

```
<input type="text" value="" id="dSuggest" />
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dSuggest").keyup(function() {
        var dInput = $(this).val();
        if(dInput == '@'){  
         $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/name",
            success: function (data) 
                {
                    console.log(data)
                    $('#view_workforce').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 0):

In your success function build your dropdown list

```
success: function(data) {
  var list = [];
  $.each(data, function(i, v) {
    list.push("<li>" + v + "</li>");
  });
  $("#dSuggest").insertAfter('<ul>' + list.join('') + '</ul>');
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it is not coming in form of a dropdown

Comment: its not a dropdown its a list, html doesn't have dropdowns

Comment: so you need to style the list as a dropdown